why bevel edge not working
When I bevel an edge this way, I also use Ctrl+A to modify the scale and rotate, but it doesn't work.


Why are you trying to rotate the edge? You should be able to apply the scale to the object in Object mode with Ctrl-A > Scale then go into Edit mode and Ctrl-B to bevel that edge but it will depend on the topology of your object. You can share your Blend file here so that we can see what you're trying to do via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Have you duplicated vertices or edges there? Flipped normals? And yes, why are you trying to rotate it?
